# Running Jboss 7.1.1 on Fedora 20 as service

Tags: jboss7.x, fedora

I have encountered a problem with running Jboss as service on Fedora. Here is the log I have after using command: `systemctl status jboss-as.service`

Here is the log I have been receiving:

```
 jboss-as.service - SYSV: JBoss AS Standalone
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-as)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Thu 2014-01-16 09:31:54 CET; 46min ago
  Process: 501 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-as start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 16 09:31:22 servername.domain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: JBoss AS Standalone...
Jan 16 09:31:23 servername.domain jboss-as[501]: Starting jboss-as: chown: missing operand after ‘/var/run/jboss-as’
Jan 16 09:31:23 servername.domain jboss-as[501]: Try 'chown --help' for more information.
Jan 16 09:31:54 servername.domain jboss-as[501]: [  OK  ]
Jan 16 09:31:54 servername.domain systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jan 16 09:31:54 servername.domain systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: JBoss AS Standalone.
Jan 16 09:31:54 servername.domain systemd[1]: Unit jboss-as.service entered failed state.
```

First, I tried to find a solution for the `chown: missin operand after ...` problem and found something: [here](http://bilalmohammedali.blogspot.com/2012/10/to-resolve-starting-jboss-as-chown.html) but it did not help. And also, I was looking for the answer for the PID file problem but it does not even exist in in the location: `var/run/jboss-as/`

Answer (score 2):

This is because the startup script uses the variable `$JBOSS_USER` but it is not defined inside the script.
Please put in the file `/etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf` the following line:

```
JBOSS_USER=root
```

(change the root with other dedicated linux user e.g. `jboss-as`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the service startup script expects to be able to write to the `/var/run/jboss-as` directory but doesn't have permissions to do so.

In your place I'd ensure that this directory is owned by the user that runs JBoss and that it is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there aren't other errors (particularly missing or incorrect paths) in your /etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss-as file (I assume you copied it from the jboss install folder to create a startup script.

I had the same issue until I fixed a completely unrelated link in that script, then it went away.

Answer (score 0):

In Centos 7, if you straight way copying the jboss-as-standalone.sh in  /etc/rc.d/init.d/, ensure JBOSS_CONF and JBOSS_HOME path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was with systemd. When I set the service y put wrong the PID File.

Example:

In the service was like

```
/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid
```

But in the script was like

```
/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as.pid
```